# Setting style for only one kind of widget

Tags: c++, qt

How can I globally change the style of one specific type of widget? I want to make all QGroupBox instances use the "plastique" style because of that nice border:

On the left, the GTK style (which I don't like); on the right, the style I want.

[image: Plastique style]
<sub>(source: [qt-project.org](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/images/gtk-groupbox.png))</sub>

[image: Plastique style]
<sub>(source: [qt-project.org](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/images/plastique-groupbox.png))</sub>

I don't want set the style for every instance of QGroupBox in the program, I want to set it globally like in QApplication::setStyle(), but only for QGroupBox. Is there a way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the [`QWidget::setStyle`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setStyle) function, on the widget you want to restyle.

If you want all group box to have the same style, you can create a subclass and use only it (there are no easiest way to restyle all instances of the same widget type):

```
class MyGroupBox: public QGroupBox
{
    public:
        MyGroupBox(QWidget* parent) : QGroupBox(parent)
        {
            setStyle(/* the style you want */);
        }
};
```

Another less convenient option is to traverse the widget tree, and set the style according to the class name of the widget.

You can also use [Qt Style Sheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html). Be aware that these are not supported with custom styles for the moment.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid that this was the only solution. It's a shame there is no static setStyle for each QWidget subclass (what would be quite unrealistic in the implementation point of view, I guess).

Comment: It seems you are thinking like in CSS (where you can style a 'class'), no ? As you said, here it is highly unrealistic for the implementation.

Comment: If I understand, one do can apply style sheet css for a 'class'. For exemple: "QLineEdit { background: yellow }" specifies that all QLineEdits should use yellow as their background color, as said in the documentation. I just cant say something like "QLineEdit { style: 'plastique' }". That would be perfect.

Comment: No, that is not possible, because style sheets are parsed and interpreted by styles; for example, if you set the style sheet `QLineEdit { background: yellow }`, the underlying style (probably `QWindowsStyle` or `QPlastiqueStyle`) will change the way it draws the line edits; that's why you can choose a style in a qss. You can make a whole "style" with qss, ie choose a style available everywhere (ex `QPlastiqueStyle`) and make a qss that change the appearance of every possible widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `qss` files for that; they are style sheets for Qt elements. As explained [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html)

In your `qss`, you can then specify a style for the `QGroupBox` class, similar to how you'd do it in `css` for HTML websites.

Comment: I see how to customize individual elements of a widget type (it's almost what I want) but I can't see how to just change the style. I mean, it would be hard to tweak all those widget elements to mimic their appearance in some style.

Comment: What do you mean? If you simply specify a style for that class, all individual elements of that class will get that style.

Comment: I can specify a style sheet for a class, OK. But how can I say "please, just use the style plastique" in css?